# Encountered error using awk in an alias command (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, alias

Good day,

Im trying to create an alias using awk to filter based on a  column which has number greater than a set limit. Its ok when used as a command line but when I assign it as an alias, it prompts error.

```
$ grep "SoftBin 108" wmap*CP1
wmap_01_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 19 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_02_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 13 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_03_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 11 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_04_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 20 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_05_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 7 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_06_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 14 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_07_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 14 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_08_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 18 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice

$ grep "SoftBin 108" wmap*CP1 | awk '$5>15'
wmap_01_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 19 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_04_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 20 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_08_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 18 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
```

`$5` is column 5 on the grep output while `15` is the set limit. When I set the alias command, it threw
read only file system for any  limit i set. I tried changing single qoute using double qoute but then it prompted a different issue.

```
$ alias SB108='grep "SoftBin 108" wmap*CP1 | awk '$5>15''
-bash: 15: Read-only file system
$ alias SB108="grep "SoftBin 108" wmap*CP1 | awk '$5>15'"
-bash: alias: 108 wmap*CP1 | awk '>15': not found
```

Ive seen some similar cases in the forum which suggest using function instead but im not familiar
with that. I tried doing it but another error was prompted.

```
$ SB108(){grep "SoftBin 108" wmap*CP1 | awk '$5>15';}
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Appreciate the help on this issue of mine. Thanks a lot in advance.

regards, Mike

Comment: Your quotes are weird. In your alias definition, you open a single quote, which goes until just after the _awk_. Hence you have the string `'grep "SoftBin 108" wmap*CP1 | awk '`. After this, you have a unquoted `$5`. Since the alias definition likely occurs inside .bashrc (otherwise it would not make much sense anyway), `$5` is unset and the null string.  After this comes a `>15` which is also outside of quotes. Therefore, you are redirecting the output of the alias command to file descriptor 15, which is the reason for the error message your got.

Comment: Hi @user1934428,thanks for the comment.Apology,im new to this thing,i thought i just need to plug these line of commands into alias and that's iy.any suggestion how this cpuld work with alias?appreciate the response.

Comment: Copying without thinking is not a good idea, in particular if quotes are involved. I think you safe yourself a lot of trouble to define your shortcut using a function instead of by an alias, because this safes you the need to provide the outer set of quotes for the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve your goal

```
[akshay@c1 tmp]$ tail -5 ~/.bashrc

test_awk() {
    grep "SoftBin 108" "$@" | awk '$5>15' 
}
export -f test_awk


# source it or logout and login back
[akshay@c1 tmp]$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Please note `The export -f feature is specific to Bash` [Refer Export Man Page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html)

**You don't have to use `grep`, single `awk` can do your job, like below**
`awk '/SoftBin 108/ && $5>15' "$@"`

#### Test below one

```
[akshay@gold tmp]$ awk '/SoftBin 108/ && $5>15' wmap* 
wmap_01_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 19 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_04_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 20 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_08_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 18 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
```

#### your sample file for testing

```
[akshay@c1 tmp]$ cat >wmap_12345_CP1<<EOF
> wmap_01_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 19 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_02_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 13 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_03_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 11 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_04_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 20 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_05_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 7 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_06_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 14 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_07_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 14 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> wmap_08_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 18 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
> EOF
```

#### call

```
[akshay@c1 tmp]$ test_awk wmap*
wmap_01_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 19 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_04_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 20 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice
wmap_08_CP1:DISP_OB:    SoftBin 108 is 18 dice exceeded Bin Reject Control limit of 7 dice

[akshay@c1 tmp]$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release
```

Comment: Good day @Akshay,appreciate the response. I will check these methods and get back to you with the feedback,thanks a lot again.By the way,do you have any suggestion to make this work in alias instead.thanks again in adavance.

Comment: Hi @Akshay Hegde, i tried your function script and it worked.Thanks a lot.This time i was able to incorporate it to an alias command and i encountered no error anymore. thanks a lot. The reaaon i insist on doing alias command is that i want to share this to my colleague who are not really "code savy" people. we're doing repetitive tasks all the time and i see alias as one way of easing our activity atleast we dont need to type so many letters or codes anymore.Thanks a lit again for the support